# Top to bottom slide gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering, if there's something like

`- (void)slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

but from top to bottom and from bottom to top

Comment: Yes. UISwipeGestureRecognizer has a direction property for possible values see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection

Comment: that's it! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right is the default direction for UISwipeGestureRecognizer, but you can set the direction with the `.direction` variable.  Check out Apple's docs on the subject [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwipeGestureRecognizer/direction).